# Microsoft Office Volume License - Where to buy

Tags: licensing, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I need to buy Microsoft Office for about 10 computers for one of my clients. Can anyone recommend where I can buy volume licenses from?

We probably only really need Outlook, Word, Excel and Access, is there a particular package that just offers those programs?

Edit: Should probably have said, I'm UK based so looking for a UK based supplier if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Grey Matter](http://www.greymatter.co.uk) are highly recommended. They have some very adept Microsoft licensing staff there who will assist you.

Comment: Updated the incorrect URL

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [PinPoint](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/smallbusiness/pinpoint/default.mspx) for the UK? Contact any of those SBS specialists and they should be able to assist you with your enquiry.

Office Professional Plus offers those plus Publisher & PowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

With volume licensing do you need to count every PC in the company or building even if you do not plan to install the software on there?

I have used Pugh and computerbox before but both were for educational licesning, schools agreement etc...

Comment: i read something on here and on a linked ms site that basically said you had to have one license per device even if they aren't all used at the same time, or if you have say 40 PCs and 30 staff, you still have to buy 40 licences... but all ours would be used all the time anyway (10 PCs)

Answer (score 0):

Volume licenses are transferable, you can buy used ones at a good discount from [Discount Licensing](http://www.discount-licensing.com/).  If you haven't got it, you'll also need a media kit (CD or DVD with the actual software to install).

Comment: thanks, this looks good.. however I'm confused...
10x Pro licences is 3825.50 exc VAT

However on ebuyer.com a Pro 2007 OEM licence is just £208 inc VAT

Whats the diffence? thats a large saving for the OEM copy...

Thanks

Comment: OEM licenses can only be purchased with hardware, and are only valid for the computer they are initially installed on.  Volume licenses are transferable from PC to PC and even from customer to customer, hence they are worth more.  (Disclaimers: I think that's a valid summary of the differences, but I am not a lawyer.  Read the fine print of the licenses before you buy them.  Offer valid in most countries, except where prohibited.)

Comment: Does that apply to Office as well as the operating system though? I read some stuff about OEM being bound to the motherboard of the first computer it was installed on, but said that it was different for applications...

If it is the case that OEM office can't be installed on a new machine, and has to be activated and all that then thats out the window, because machines are likely to get upgraded

Comment: Yes, what I wrote applies to OEM licenses in general, that's pretty much what OEM licensing means.  That's why OEM licenses are cheaper.  A search for "OEM license office" will find plenty of sites discussing it; there's a pretty good overview here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/EULAFAQ.htm.  And yes, upgrading can require re-activation if the hardware changes sufficiently.  Is it worth trying to talk your client into OpenOffice.org?  It's free, *NO* licensing issues, as many PCs as you want. Never any upgrade costs, so you can have the same version on all PCs.